# How to convert Pandas Dataframe columns of String type to a SET in JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, set

I have a pandas dataframe whose each entry in to_json(orient="records") format returns :

```
{
    "applicationType": "IMPALA",
    "user": "root",
    "id": "705c64ad",
    "category_2": "{ \"tag\": \"uncategorised\",\"tag_type\":\"uncategorised\" }",
    "category_5": "{ \"tag\": \"HR\",\"tag_type\":\"Management\" }",
    "category_8": "{ \"tag\": \"uncategorised\",\"tag_type\":\"uncategorised\" }"
}
```

If Dataframe is operated using to_dict(orient="records") it returns the following data in Dictionary format :

```
{
'applicationType': 'IMPALA',
'user': 'root',
'id': '705c64ad', 
'category_2': '{ "tag": "uncategorised","tag_type":"uncategorised" }',
'category_5': '{ "tag": "HR","tag_type":"Management" }', 
'category_8': '{ "tag": "uncategorised","tag_type":"uncategorised" }'
}
```

I want to process the above data to produce a JSON that should be a SET having unique entries in a tag called "category" for all "category_*" columns of dataframe as follows

```
{
    "applicationType": "IMPALA",
    "user": "root",
    "id": "705c64ad",
    "category": [{ "tag": "uncategorised","tag_type":"uncategorised" }, { "tag": "HR","tag_type":"Management" }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json
json_data = '''{
  "applicationType": "IMPALA",
  "user": "root",
  "id": "705c64ad",
  "category_2": {
    "tag": "uncategorised",
    "tag_type": "uncategorised"
  },
  "category_5": {
    "tag": "HR",
    "tag_type": "Management"
  },
  "category_8": {
    "tag": "uncategorised",
    "tag_type": "uncategorised"
  }
}'''
data = json.loads(json_data)

res = {x: data[x] for x in data if 'category' not in x}
res['category'] = [dict(y) for y in {tuple(data[x].items()) for x in data if 'category' in x}]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'applicationType': 'IMPALA', 'user': 'root', 'id': '705c64ad', 'category': [{'tag': 'uncategorised', 'tag_type': 'uncategorised'}, {'tag': 'HR', 'tag_type': 'Management'}]}
```